# Can infrared light pass through solid materials?

Tags: infrared, photodiode, phototransistor, photonics

I have an IR sensor at about few tens of mm (millimeter) from a heating source (incandescent bulb or heating element.) The phototransistor in my sensor is lead lined but I guess it is sensitive to a wide range of IR. The IR sensor and the heating source are to be separated by either a powder coated mild steel sheet, or stainless steel sheet, or transparent Perspex, or black PVC sheet, or the regular brown cardboard sheet.

I would like to avoid any noise from this heating source in my IR sensor.

I guess some interference might be expected when using transparent Perspex, but is interference to be expected with the other opaque options?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150257/discussion-on-question-by-iskander-can-infrared-light-pass-through-solid-materia); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many common plastics are transparent to near IR. If your goal is to block NIR, do not use an unverified plastic. Paper and cardboard do block near IR though. In this regard, metal sheet or metal foil tends to be safest.

Answer (score 2):

Your sensor receives some IR energy from the sheets that you are using for isolation.

Thanks to Planck, we all know that IR is solely dependent on the temperature of bodies.

That means that your IR sensor is receiving IR energy from the sheets that are at 293 kelvin.

The energy from the sheets is noise and the energy from the source is signal

You have to design your system in order to maximize the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Thanks. I'll build a real part and see the results. Maybe I am just too concerned. We have IR all around us after all, never had any trouble. And now with slight physical design modifications this heat source is going even further from the sensor, and more barriers would be possibly coming its way.